# If a function has a jump discontinuity on $x_0$, is its antiderivative undefined for $x_0$ or does it exist?

Tags: calculus

Asking because for a function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x&\text{for $x<0$}, \\
1&\text{for $x\geq 0$},
\end{cases}
$$
if $F(0)$ really does exist and is equal to $0$, that is conflicted with there being no derivative of $F(x)$ in $0$. And if $F(0)$ is undefined, then no function with jump discontinuity seemingly has antiderivative at that point.

Comment: True, all deriavtives have intermediate value property.